# How to split one column into 2 columns in hive table?

Tags: sql, hive, hue

I want to split the name column into 2 columns where there are many hiphens(-) in the name but I want to split from the last hiphen(-) HiveQL in hive db.

for example check the check the below table

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| a-b-c-d_b | 22 |
| d-e-f-g_e | 44 |

I want the output to be like splitting the name column with only last (-)

So the output table should be like the one below

| name | age | new_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a-b-c-d_b | 22 | d_b |
| d-e-f-g_e | 44 | g_e |

Answer (score 0):

Please use below SQL.

First reverse the string and then split the string using `-` and pick up first split.
Then reverse again to get desired string. You can refer to below screenshot.

```
select reverse(split( reverse(name),'-')[0]) as new_name
```

[image]